# Pathauto not working

Tags: path-aliases

I had installed pathauto module and it was generating desired url alias. But now its not working. All the newly created node shows node/node->nid. This issue stops working of my drupal_get_path_alias function i added in views template. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: The issue is with a single content type. If i made a bulk url update using pathauto, it works. Is there way to add bulk update in cron jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by commenting $form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false; line in my template.php. Still i don't know why that issue happens for a single content type.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with redirects. To overcome this problem, follow below steps:

1. Go to URL: admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk
2. Select option to delete all aliases.[image]
3. Go to URL : admin/config/search/path
4. See if there are no aliases left, if any left delete them too. [image]
5. If you have redirect module installed, go to URL: admin/config/search/redirect and delete all redirects if any.[image]
6. Recreated all URL aliases, go to URL: admin/config/search/path/update_bulk and select desired URL aliases to be created.[image]

   See if problem is fixed. If you still have issues comment below.

Comment: I didn't installed any re-direct module. But i deleted all allias and re created. Still issue exists.

Comment: can you also uninstall pathauto once and do follow above steps ?

Comment: Don't just disable, do complete uninstall and install again